# How to import sql dump to docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a sql dump which contains main sql and .dat files. I have a docker container with Postgres but I dont know how to import this dump to Posgres container. I tried to do it via Pgamin and also through docker terminal.
Pgadmin dos not recognize commands like
`\connect tenant_00003` or `select * from stdin`.
Docker terminal can not find the file on disc.

Can somebody tell me please how to do it?

Comment: You could use `docker cp` to copy the SQL dump into the container and then import the file via the command line inside the container.